# How to call a BigQuery Function in Jupyter notebook

Tags: google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I use Jupyterhub to run BigQuery SQL and the usual syntax for my queries is:

```
import google.datalab.bigquery as bq

sql_qry = "select * from table"

query = bq.Query(sql_qry)
sql_job = query.execute(output_options = bq.QueryOutput.table(name='output_table',
                                                              mode='overwrite'))
```

But I am trying to use a BigQuery function on Jupyterhub:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION first_letter(x STRING) AS (
SUBSTR(x, 1, 1)
);
```

Any idea how I can parse this? I can certainly just add it as a string to each query but because of the syntax I can't simply sequentially run that query with other queries in the same string.

Comment: Can you provide examples of the queries that you are trying to run? I don't understand this part of your problem: "because of the syntax I can't simply sequentially run that query with other queries in the same string"

Comment: Make this into a persistent function by removing `temp`.  Then just incorporate its usage into your `sel_qry`.  `select *, project.dataset.fn_first_letter(field) from table`.  https://medium.com/@hoffa/new-in-bigquery-persistent-udfs-c9ea4100fd83

Comment: Yeah exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know you could create persistent functions and save them in the database. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can save you function in a sql file, then in JupyterHub read that file, save it in a variable and send it to [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query), something like this:

```
sql_file = file('function.sql', 'r')
sql = sql_file.read()
sql_file.close()

query_data = {
    'query': sql
}
```

In addition, if you are using Jupyter, you can use the [BigQuery Magic Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter)